# How much of my season bank loot will attackers get when they raid my village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

After getting the season bank reward, my gold and elixir storages will be at 25,000,000.

I can't spend this that quickly so assuming my storages stay that way when I get attacked, will the attacker be able to gain a portion of my bonus, walking away with *massive* loot gains, or is the amount they can take capped somehow?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Clash of Clans wikia](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Multiplayer_Battles):

> The percentage of Gold/Elixir that can be stolen from storages until TH6 is 20% and is capped at 200,000. At TH7 and up, the percentage that can be stolen drops by 2% at each TH level, to a minimum of 10% at TH11 and above, while the cap increases by 50k at each TH level, to a maximum of 600,000 at TH14.

Here's a chart:

| Town Hall Level | % Available to be Stolen | Cap | Storage Amount to Reach Cap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20% | 500 | 2,500 |
| 2 | 20% | 1,700 | 8,500 |
| 3 | 20% | 20,000 | 100,000 |
| 4 | 20% | 100,000 | 500,000 |
| 5-6 | 20% | 200,000 | 1,000,000 |
| 7 | 18% | 250,000 | 1,388,889 |
| 8 | 16% | 300,000 | 1,875,000 |
| 9 | 14% | 350,000 | 2,500,000 |
| 10 | 12% | 400,000 | 3,333,333 |
| 11 | 10% | 450,000 | 4,500,000 |
| 12 | 10% | 500,000 | 5,000,000 |
| 13 | 10% | 550,000 | 5,500,000 |
| 14 | 10% | 600,000 | 6,000,000 |

The amount of stolen loot varies depending on the defender’s and also attacker’s Town Hall levels and how much loot the defender has in storage.

Luckily, there's a [calculator](https://pixelcrux.com/Clash_of_Clans/Available_Loot/Calculator) that should answer your question. And since I don't have all the needed info, you may want to try by yourself.